# Newbie Problem with integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

when I type `Integrate[Sign[x], x]` to *Mathematica*, the answer is `∫Sign[x] dx`
so nothing new. When I type the same to Wolfram Alpha, I get a solved integral: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSign%5Bx%5D%2C+x%5D

Someone Any idea what to do otherwise? Would be really thankful for help!

Comment: Try `Integrate[Sign[x], {x, a, b}]`

Comment: Or `Integrate[Sign[x], x, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]`

Comment: Hey Belisarius,
thanks a lot for your comment!
But both of it, dont return a proper integral.

Integrate[Sign[x], {x, a, b}]
returns
ConditionalExpression[-Abs[a] + Abs[b], Re[a] < b && a == Re[a]]

and
Integrate[Sign[x], x, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
returns
a small table:
-x     x<=0
x      True

any other ideas?

Comment: The result is correct and equivalent to the alpha result, though in a somewhat different form.  ( Mathematica omits the "plus a constant" for the indefinite form, is that the issue? )

Comment: Hi George,
yes thats the problem. Do you know, how I can change the indefinite form , in the how you call it "plus a constant form"?

PS: Sorry for my english, I try my best

Comment: `Integrate[Sign[x], x, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]] + C[1]` -- i.e., add the constant yourself, since it will predictably be missing.

Comment: @Phawi You should write @ plus the user name when responding. This makes sure that the person you are responding to gets notified of your response. I did it at the beginning of this comment just as an example.  The author of a post is always notified when a comment is left, with or without @.

Comment: @Michael E2,
first thank you all. In that short time, three persons tried to help me, wow!
sadly its still not returning a proper result. maybe a screenshot is better for understanding: [link](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151215/p2xu5rmn.png)

Comment: `Simplify[Integrate[Sign[x], x, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]] - 
  x*Sign[x]]` gives 0

Answer (score 3):

As belisarius said in the comments, you need to assume `x` is a real variable:

```
res = Integrate[Sign[x], x, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{-x, x <= 0}}, x]
> ```

To get the result Alpha gets, we need to actually make use of an *internal* function that expresses piecewise function in terms of `UnitStep`.

```
Simplify[Simplify`PWToUnitStep[res] /. UnitStep[f_] :> (Sign[f] + 1)/2]
```

> ```
> x Sign[x]
> ```

I think the real take away from your question though should really be the first part of this answer, i.e. you need to assume `x` is real to integrate this function.

Comment: ok after playing around with your solution for more than an hour I have still problems with it, but I will continue trying and Reading… Hopefully I will get a way to understand it. Thanks a lot for your support! =)

Comment: @Phawi What seems to be the issue? Does the code not work if you copy, paste, and run it?

Comment: its working fine, but I have problems to abstract the solution. For Example I want to integrate `Sign[Sin[2 \[Pi] x] ` 
Using your way: `Simplify[Simplify`PWToUnitStep[
   Integrate[Sign[Sin[2 \[Pi] x]], x, 
    Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]] /.` Result is `x Sign[Sin[2 \[Pi] x]]` 
So, now I try to verificative this, by using the defined integral function: `Integrate[Sign[Sin[2 \[Pi] x]], {x, 0, 1.5}]` returns `0.5` (correct)
Now I try getting same result while using the in defined integral:
`1.5* Sign[Sin[2 \[Pi]*1.5]]-0* Sign[Sin[2 \[Pi]*0]]` returns `1.5`, what is wrong

Comment: Look at the plot here: `res = Integrate[Sign[Sin[2 \[Pi] x]], x, 
   Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals];
Plot[res, {x, 0, 3/2}]` There are jump discontinuities, and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus requires the antiderivative to be continuous. This means you need to add a piecewise constant to your function to make it continuous before you can use FToC. [Here's](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) a great link explaining what I'm talking about.